# New autoref categories

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, tcolorbox, autoref

I have a document in which I define new environment for examples (MWE below). In it, I define the prefix for referencing it, which is simple `example:nameofexample`.

Now, when working with `\autoref` I can simply write `\autoref{eq:name}` and the result is written along the lines of `Equation 1.37` (i.e. the word "Equation" is prefixed to the referenced equation number). I do this by defining

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\equationautorefname{Equation}
```

I would like to do something similar with autorefs to an example, e.g.
\def\exampleautorefname{Example}

How do I do that?

The MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{xblue}{HTML}{4268BD}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    common/.style n args={2}{
        colframe={#1},
        colback={#1!5},
        colbacktitle={#1},
        lower separated=false,
        coltitle=white,
        boxrule=1pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        top=8pt,
        before skip=1em,
        after skip=2em,
        attach boxed title to top left={
            yshift=-0.25cm,
            xshift=0.38cm,
        },
        boxed title style={
            boxrule=0pt,
            colframe=white,
            arc=5pt,
            outer arc=4pt,
        },
        separator sign={~~},
        overlay unbroken and last={
            \node[text=white, align=right, rounded corners, fill=#1, xshift=-4mm, minimum height=6mm, anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {#2};
        }
    },
    examplestyle/.style={
        common={xblue}{!},
    },
}
\newtcbtheorem{example}{Example}{examplestyle}{example}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\equationautorefname{Equation}
\def\exampleautorefname{Example}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
This is an example box:
\begin{example}{This is an example}{myexample}
    \blindtext[1]
\end{example}

And here is an equation:
\begin{equation}
    a+b=c
    \label{eq:myeq}
\end{equation}

\vspace{1em}
Now I try to autorefence both the equation and the example: \autoref{example:myexample} and \autoref{eq:myeq}. While in the case of the autoref to the equation, it shows ``Eqaution 1``. For the example autoref though, it only shows ``1``. How can I add new categories to autoref so that it instead shows ``Example 1``?
\end{document}
```

The result of compiling the above code:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look into the log you will see that hyperref tells you what is missing

```
Package hyperref Warning: No autoref name for `tcb@cnt@example' on input line 9
```

`tcb@cnt@example` is the internal counter name used by tcolorbox.
So add

```
\makeatletter
\def\tcb@cnt@exampleautorefname{Example}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you :)
(und frohe Ostern!)